# What is the correct pattern to validate such in address field in json schema

Tags: json, validation, json-schema-validator

How to validate that the "street" should contain only upper case. Though it can contain number and spaces

For example:
should accept below

- 1 ABC ST
- 1 ABCST
- ABCST
- ABCST 1

should not accept below

- 1 aBC ST
- 1 ABCSt
- ABcST
- abcst 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html) to constrain a string. In your case it would be something like this.

```json
{
   "type": "string",
   "pattern": "^[ A-Z0-9]+$"
}
```

You can make the regular expression more advanced to not allow leading and trailing space etc.

Comment: Thanks alot Martin Liversage. Appreciate your prompt response. It worked fine